# Asp.Net Core 5 MVC Getting value from JS to Model

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project. I have an inserted integer count value with javascript into local storage in another view. When I pass this page I need to get that value to my Model (also an integer) and print different things to the page according to this value.

I tried to get it like this :

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var count = localStorage.getItem('count');
            @Model = count;
        });
    </script>

    <input type="hidden" id="hdnCountCart" name="hdnCountCart" value="0" />
    <h2 class="text-center mb-3">Sepetim</h2>
    @if (@Model == 0)
    {
        do something..
    }
    else { 
       do something else..
    }
```

or from hidden input but it didn't work. Also checked online but people usually get value **to JS from Model**.

**Edit:** I know I can print to the page what I want only using JS here. I just want to know is there a way to local storage to model.

Comment: I think we're going to need to see more code than this.

Comment: You would need to post the value of localstorage using a form or an AJAX request before the view is rendered. There is no other way foe your view model to see the value from localstorage.